# Will ON DELETE CASCADE delete a parent even if another child has it as parent?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-delete, create-table

This is a question about the behavior of MySQL (I have version 8.0.18 for what it's worth) when you delete a row in a table that was created with a `DELETE ON CASCADE` clause.

Suppose I have these 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE parents (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE children (
    id INT, 
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Let's also suppose that I have inserted some data in them, so that parents looks like this:

```
id
--
1
2
```

and children looks like this:

```
id | parent_id
--------------
1  |    1
2  |    1
```

Now suppose that I do this:

```
DELETE FROM children WHERE parent_id='1'
```

My question is whether, because of the `ON DELETE CASCADE` in the query I used to create `children`, this will also delete the row in `parents` whose `id` is 1, even though there is another row in `children` that also has it as parent? Based on what I have read about the behavior of `ON DELETE CASCADE` so far, it seems to be the case, but this isn't very smart. So, in other words, I want to know if `ON DELETE CASCADE` is that dumb.

I tried to figure it out myself by testing the example I just described, but for some reason `ON CASCADE DELETE` doesn't seem to work at all on my local server at the moment (nothing is deleted in `parents` even when I delete the second child in `children`, so there is no remaining child in `children` that refers to the parent whose id is 1 in `parents`), so while I'm figuring out why I thought that I should ask this question here because I'm probably not the only person who has wondered about that and the answer will be useful to other people.

Comment: Parents delete children, children never delete parents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a misconception here. The foreign key binds a child to a parent - but not the other way around.

You seem to assume that `on delete cascade` deletes the parent when a child is removed. This is not the case: when a parent is deleted, the related children are deleted as well.

Here is [an example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=377125cc27852063e2d049582e48517a) based on your setup:

```
create table parents (
    id int not null,
    primary key (id)
);

create table children (
    id int, 
    parent_id int,
    foreign key (parent_id) references parents(id) on delete cascade
);

-- parent 1 has two children, parent 2 has one child
insert into parents values (1), (2);
insert into children values (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2);

-- delete parent 1
delete from parents where id = 1;

-- related children where deleted
select * from children;

id | parent_id
-: | --------:
 3 |         2
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I was just confused. This also explains why I thought that ```ON DELETE CASCADE``` wasn’t working on my local server. This is kind of embarrassing, I should have thought about it more before asking this question, but at least I don’t have to worry about this anymore!

Answer (score 3):

It works the other way around:
If you delete the parent itself, the children get deleted.

If you delete any of the children, even if you delete all of them, the parent will stay.
This is because the point of the ON DELETE CASCADE rule is to prevent a children from having a non-existent parent, and not to prevent a parent that doesnt have children